# Can one open up the same workbook and worksheet using interop multiple times in a program?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am using Excel Interop commands in order to open up a workbook/worksheet to read and print on. I have a print and a read class and I have the workbook being opened up in both classes. The read class opens it up just fine but when I try to open the workbook in the print class I get a null pointer exception. Am I allowed to open the same workbook twice or should I only do it once and pass it in as a parameter to the print class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it once - excel (and interop) are opening the file in exclusive mode.
Also, opening it once has lots of architectural benefits: faster load times, easier code, less chance for race conditions etc.